# How to count rows in table using AFC - Advance custom field Repeater

Tags: wordpress

Hy,

im using Wordpress plugin Advance Custon Field PRO, i make a repeater field, in that repeater field i have 4 field(Imagine, Nume, Evaluare, Verificati pretul)

How can i display numbers automate the rows.
Ex: 
1 - first row
2 - second row

I don't want to put manualy for each row.

thanks in advance

```
<?php if( have_rows('tabel_produse_profit') ): ?>

    <table width="100%" class="tab">
      <tr>
        <td>Nr.</td>
        <td>Imagine</td>
        <td>Nume</td>
        <td>Evaluare</td>
        <td>Verificati pretul</td>
      </tr>

        <?php while( have_rows('tabel_produse_profit') ): the_row(); 
            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('tabel_imagine_produs');
            $link = get_sub_field('tabel_link_profit');
            $titlu = get_sub_field('tabel_titlu_profit');
            $evaluare = get_sub_field('tabel_evaluare');
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="row1">

                </td>
               <td class="row2">
                    <?php if( $image ): ?>
                        <img class="imag" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
               </td>
               <td class="row3">
                    <?php if( $titlu ): ?>
                        <h2><?php echo $titlu; ?></h2>
                    <?php endif; ?>
               </td>
               <td class="row4">
                    <?php if( $evaluare ): ?>
                        <div class="eva"><?php echo $evaluare; ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
               </td>
               <td class="row5">
                    <?php if( $link ): ?>
                        <a class="ver" href="<?php echo $link; ?>">VERIFICAȚI PREȚUL</a>
                        <div class="mag">pe emag.ro</div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
               </td>
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </tr>
          <?php endwhile; ?>  
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if( have_rows('tabel_produse_profit') ): ?>

<table width="100%" class="tab">
  <tr>
    <td>Nr.</td>
    <td>Imagine</td>
    <td>Nume</td>
    <td>Evaluare</td>
    <td>Verificati pretul</td>
  </tr>

    <?php $i = 1;
        while( have_rows('tabel_produse_profit') ): the_row(); 
        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('tabel_imagine_produs');
        $link = get_sub_field('tabel_link_profit');
        $titlu = get_sub_field('tabel_titlu_profit');
        $evaluare = get_sub_field('tabel_evaluare');
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="row1">
             <?php echo $i; ?>
            </td>
           <td class="row2">
                <?php if( $image ): ?>
                    <img class="imag" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
           </td>
           <td class="row3">
                <?php if( $titlu ): ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $titlu; ?></h2>
                <?php endif; ?>
           </td>
           <td class="row4">
                <?php if( $evaluare ): ?>
                    <div class="eva"><?php echo $evaluare; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
           </td>
           <td class="row5">
                <?php if( $link ): ?>
                    <a class="ver" href="<?php echo $link; ?>">VERIFICAȚI PREȚUL</a>
                    <div class="mag">pe emag.ro</div>
                <?php endif; ?>
           </td>
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        </tr>
      <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>  
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank's for the reply but i figured out.